# How to get real lat lon values (degrees) of line geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I have a line layer in QGIS. The project CRS is WGS84 (4326) and the layer CRS too. The goal is to have the coordinates of the line nodes in a csv - one row/field per line.

Now I tried copy/paste of the attribute table to excel to get the geometry from the hidden wkt_geom column and also tried calculating a new filed with geom_to_wkt($geometry). The thing is: I do get a list of coordinate values, but they look like this:

```
1025757.69916104024741799 6299395.96179542783647776
```

WhenI expect them to look like this:

```
49.144401, 9.214915
```

This is probably a simple conversion or settings problem, but I'm stuck trying to find out what exactly I'm doing wrong here.

**UPDATE:**
I tried again to get the same points from my project file and from googlemaps (which is also my background tile layer for the project so should be the same)

My project:

```
LineString (1025848.60394998698029667 6299398.59839912224560976, 1025839.35096344409976155 6299388.28413813747465611)
```

google

```
49.144401, 9.215357 - 49.144342, 9.215275
```

Also this is a brandnew test project with exactly one layer containing this one line of two nodes. I set the CRS for the project, the layer and the background google maps layer to WGS 84:
[image: Project CRS]
[image: Layer CRS]

sorry for the german interface, but I think you can still see the CRS I've chosen. I really don't know what I should do differently...

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show us coordinates you get and the city/places coordinates you would expect for the same city/places? It's to help find you the projection. Asking because not sure the coordinates you already provided are exact?!

Comment: Your layer CRS has been set wrongly at some point - probably by the use of `Set Layer CRS` which doesn't change the projection of the layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I could not get QGIS 3.12 to output the degree values in a csv.

Quite desparete I downloaded QGIS 2.18 and, lo and behold, it worked. Set the display coordinates to degrees in the project properties and just copy/paste the attribute table to Excel worked like a charm.